# GCP Deployment Manager: where to find a reference guide to properly create YAML config and template files?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, deployment-manager

I started working with Google Cloud Deployment Manager upon request of a client, using YAML config files, but I can't find anywhere how to map the reference shown in https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types to what I'm actually using.

Particularly, I need to attach an existent external elastic IP to an instance at creation time, but I can't find anywhere what is the config file schema to do so (i.e. like with `eksctl` config file schema documentation found at https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/):

```yaml
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: nextcloud-vm
  properties:
    natIP: nextcloud-vm
    # The properties of the resource depend on the type of resource. For a list
    # of properties, see the API reference for the resource.
    zone: us-west1-a
    # Replace martin-dev-391362 with your project ID
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/martin-dev-391362/zones/us-west1-a/machineTypes/n2-standard-4
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        # See a full list of image families at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support
        # The format of the sourceImage URL is: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[IMAGE_PROJECT]/global/images/family/[FAMILY_NAME]
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/family/ubuntu-2004-lts
        diskSizeGb: 20
    # Replace martin-dev-391362 with your project ID
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/martin-dev-391362/global/networks/default
      # Access Config required to give the instance a public IP address
      accessConfigs:
      - name: nextcloud-vm
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

The above code doesn't work because it tries to create a new IP address with that name instead of using the already existing elastic IP address. Thing is I can't find *anywhere* what is the correct notation :)

I'd really appreciate if anybody can point me to the right direction because solving this very little issue is just the tip of the iceberg, as I will be working a lot with Deployment Manager and thus I need to get the complete picture on how to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the yaml below as reference and just replace `mystatic` with the name of your reserved External IP on VPC Network. But when you delete your deployment, it will also delete your [Static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses) as part of the deployment.

```
resources:
- name: mystatic
  type: compute.v1.address
  properties:
    region: us-central1
  
- name: vm-created-by-deployment-manager
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-a
    machineType: zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        sourceImage: projects/debian-cloud/global/images/family/debian-10
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
        natIP: $(ref.mystatic.address)
```

You'd want to check out the [Compute API Reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1) for a list of properties you can use on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex! I believe it will be easier now that I've got your definition example to get a better understanding on how to use API reference.

Comment: Adding on the already stupendous Alex's answer, I'd like to also add that this very link holds all the information you need to properly work with your YAML file: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types -- HTH ^_^